# Verifying a formula for $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}w_x$, where $w = f(x,y)$, $x = u + v$, and $y = u - v$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> If I have $w = f(x,y)$, where $x = u + v$ and $y = u - v$, then why is the following true?
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}w_x = \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

Is my assumption that $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}w_x = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial u 
\partial x}$ incorrect since $w_x = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$?

Lastly,

> How does that imply the following?
> $$\frac{\partial w_x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = w_{xx} + w_{xy}$$

Comment: It is called The Chain Rule.

Comment: @geetha290krm is my assumption correct or are they different values?

Comment: @EAO123 The problem is that there are two ways of using $w$ here: either as a function of $x,y$ or as a function of $u,v$. It's a sort of convention that when we write double derivatives $\frac{\partial w}{\partial\alpha\partial\beta}$ we should either have $\alpha,\beta\in\{x,y\}$ or $\alpha,\beta\in\{u,v\}$, we shouldn't mix them like you have done. It's OKish to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$ but $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial u \partial x}$ seems to me confusing.

Comment: The last line is close to being total nonsense. $$\frac{\partial w_x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$ is a function of $u$ and $v$ while $w_{xx}+w_{xy}$ is a function of $x$ and $y\,.$ Morale: don't suppress arguments if you want to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If I have $w = f(x,y)$, where $x = u + v$ and $y = u - v$, then why is the following true?
> > $$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}w_x = \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$
>
> Is my assumption that $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}w_x = \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial u 
> \partial x}$ incorrect since $w_x = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$?

Not exactly. The notation of $\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial u\partial x}$ should be avoided, since it is not a double derivative of independent variables ($x$ being dependent on $u$ and $v$).

Also, we should *preferably* use one style or the other, rather than mix notations, to avoid confusions.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}&=\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\,^2}\cdot\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y\,\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}\\[1ex] [w_x]_u &= w_{xx}x_u +w_{xy}y_u\end{align}$$

> Lastly,
>
> > How does that imply the following?
> > $$\frac{\partial w_x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w_x}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = w_{xx} + w_{xy}$$

Well, because $x = u + v$ and $y = u - v$, therefore ...

Comment: this makes sense, thank you!